# Periodicity and Multiplicativity of Dirichlet characters

Tags: number-theory

In Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory (page 2), Dirichlet characters mod (prime) q are defined as $w^{v(n)}$ where $w$ is a real or complex number satisfying $w^{q-1} =1$, and $v(n)=v$ denotes the index of $n$ relative to a fixed primitive root $g$ of modulo $q$ so that $g^v \equiv n\mod q$. I can see that the function $w^{v(n)}$ is periodic with $\mod q$, since $v(n) = v(n+qt)$ for $t = 1,2,3,...$. It is given that if $n \equiv n_1 n_2 \mod q$, then $v(n) \equiv v(n_1) + v(n_2) \mod q-1$, which gives multiplicativity of the function $w^{v(n)}$. I could not understand the first implication: If $n \equiv n_1 n_2 \mod q$, then $v(n) = v(n_1 n_2)$ by the periodicity. I do not see why $v(n) \equiv v(n_1) + v(n_2) \mod q-1$. It seems to me instead of $\mod q-1$, there should be $\mod q$, which is wrong. If I assume this implication, it follows that $w^{v(n_1 n_2)}= w^{v(n_1)}w^{v(n_2)}$ having $w^{q-1} =1$ so we get the multiplicativity. I appreciate any help!

Comment: The reason the exponents are periodic modulo $q-1$ instead of $q$ is Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @GregMartin's apt comment, I'd claim that this is a not-so-clear (while seemingly elementary) description of what a character $\chi$ of a cyclic group $C$ (or abelian group, or non-abelian...) is.

Namely, first, a character $\chi$ on the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/p)^\times$ (for $p$ prime) of $\mathbb Z/p$ is a group homomorphism $(\mathbb Z/p)^\times \to \mathbb C^\times$. Extending this by $\chi(0)=0$ is the standard way to define a "Dirichlet character".

So, yes, $\chi(a+p)=\chi(a)$, *and* $\chi(a)^{p-1}=1$ for $a\not=0$ mod $p$, since $(\mathbb Z/p)^\times$ is cyclic of order $p-1$.